# System.ArgumentException: Invalid argument for the equals operator. Filter[0] cannot be null or empty

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am using Ampscript to update subscriber status in All Subscriber list. I have created a filter which filters subscribers having same Email Address. Then by using SubscriberKey of these subscribers i am master unsubscribing them all. However the code is working fine but salesforce gave me the following error :

> PartnerAPICommon.PartnerAPIBaseException: Failed SOAP Api
>   RetreiveRequest (see inner ex):

---

```
{ 
"ObjectType": "Subscriber", 
"Properties": [ 
"EmailAddress", 
"SubscriberKey", 
"Status" 
], 
"Filter": { 
"Property": "EmailAddress", 
"SimpleOperator": 0, 
"Value": [ 
"" 
], 
"DateValue": null 
}, 
"ClientIDs": null, 
"RespondTo": null, 
"PartnerProperties": null, 
"ContinueRequest": null, 
"QueryAllAccounts": false, 
"QueryAllAccountsSpecified": false, 
"RetrieveAllSinceLastBatch": false, 
"RetrieveAllSinceLastBatchSpecified": false, 
"RepeatLastResult": false, 
"RepeatLastResultSpecified": false, 
"Retrieves": null, 
"Options": null 
}
```

---

> > System.ArgumentException: Invalid argument for the equals operator. Filter[0] cannot be null or empty.  at
> >     PartnerAPICommon.APIHandlerBase.TranslateFilterpartToPredicate(SimpleFilterPart
> >     parseFilter, String objectType, Type t)  at
> >     PartnerAPICommon.APIHandlerBase.BuildWhereClauseFromFilterPart(FilterPart
> >     filter, String objectType, Type t)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
>   Category: Partner API  Error Code: SOAPRetrieve

Code :

```
    %%[
set @email = "abc@abc.com"
SET @rr = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")  
SetObjectProperty(@rr, "ObjectType", "Subscriber")  
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","EmailAddress")  
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","SubscriberKey")  
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","Status")


SET @sfp = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")  
SetObjectProperty(@sfp, "Property", "EmailAddress")  
SetObjectProperty(@sfp, "SimpleOperator", "equals")  
AddObjectArrayItem(@sfp, "Value", @email)    
SetObjectProperty(@rr, "Filter", @sfp)  
SET @sub = InvokeRetrieve(@rr)

SET @Count = rowCount(@sub)

for @i = 1 to @Count do 

SET @row1 = Row(@sub,@i)   
SET @SubscriberKey = Field(@row1 ,"SubscriberKey") 
SET @status1 = Field(@row1, "Status")


SET @sid = @emailcheck 
SET @all = @allCheck 
SET @reason = "Custom Profile Center Unsubscribe" 
SET @lue = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest") 
SetObjectProperty(@lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent") 

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty") 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey") 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @SubscriberKey)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop) 

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty") 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "ListID") 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value",24) 

AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop) 
SET @lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@lue, @overallStatus, @requestId) 
SET @Response = Row(@lue_statusCode, 1) 
SET @Status = Field(@Response,"StatusMessage") 
SET @Error = Field(@Response,"ErrorCode")

OutputLine(concat(@SubscriberKey, @status1))
OutputLine(concat(@Status, @Error))

next @i

]%%
```

Comment: I believe your issue is where it says `"Value": [ "" ]` in the 'inner ex,' which indicates to me that you're passing in a null or empty email address. The only issue I can see with your code above might be where you're doing `set @email = "abc@abc.com"`. AMPScript isn't supposed to be case-sensitive, but SFMC is finicky, so I wouldn't be surprised if changing `set` to `SET` would resolve your issue.